# Implement responder with dynamic status code

Tags: rust, rust-rocket

I'm implementing a generic error responder to handle errors in the rocket rust web framework.
Following the docs here:
https://rocket.rs/v0.5-rc/guide/responses/#custom-responders

This responder works for me:

```
#[derive(Responder)]
#[response(status= 500, content_type = "json")]
struct ServerError {
    inner: String,
}
```

But I would like to make the status code dynamic. The docs state this:

> Because ContentType and Status are themselves headers, you can also
> dynamically set the content-type and status by simply including fields
> of these types.

So I tried adding `status` to my struct like so:

```
use rocket::response::status;

#[derive(Responder)]
#[response(status= 500, content_type = "json")]
struct ServerError {
    inner: String,
    status: Status
}

#[get("/")]
async fn index() -> Result<String, ServerError> {
    Err(ServerError{
        inner: String::from("error"),
        status: Status::InternalServerError
    })
}
```

I get the following error:

```
47  |     status: Status
    |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `From<Status>` is not implemented for `rocket::http::Header<'_>`
```

Is there a way to implement an error responder with a dynamic status without having to explicitly implement `Responder` and just relying on derive ?

Comment: Reported a bug: https://github.com/SergioBenitez/Rocket/issues/2484.